# How To Distinguish One Music File From The Other

Tags: ios, audio

I am currently building a music player app. One of the functions of my app is "My Favorites". This is nothing different from other music player apps, for it allows user to mark down their favorite songs, and when they want to play only their favorite songs, they can play them directly from the "My Favorites" list.

My problem now is that in order for me to remember and be able to play that song next time, I think I have to remember the UNIQUE ID of that song. I am not sure if there is really a UNIQUE ID for every music file stored in the phone. I just thought of that because if there is, it would be a key for me to access that music file.

The solution I tried is appending the name of the music and the artist and use it as the key. Then, I will get the music list and run a loop through it, once I find the corresponding music file by comparing it with the key I will store it in an `NSMutableDictionary`. Then I will be able to play it later.

The problem of my solution is that what id two music files have exactly the same artist name and same title. That I won't be able to distinguish which is which.

I hope I made my self clear. To summarize:

Problem: Is there a way to get the UNIQUE ID of a music file. If there isn't are there any other ways to determine one music file from the other?

Comment: And what kind of music file are you using? If you use `MPMediaItem` there is `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` which is unique (cf. documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaItem_ClassReference/index.html)

Comment: Could you post some of your code so we can see what objects you are using? Like Larme said, are you using `MPMediaItem`?

Comment: @Larme Thank you for the info! I'll try using that.

Comment: @Joze yes, I am using MPMediaItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @Larme suggested. I could use `MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID` for the unique ID of my music files, and that is what I've applied, and it is the right answer for me.

Thank you @Larme!